# How to return a particular value from a method?

Tags: ruby

I have this code that tries to return a value from a method:

```
temp = "123"
return temp
```

and I have this line that calls the method and assigns the return value:

```
person_connections = @client.get_person_connections(:id => current_user_id )
```

but when I try to inspect `person_connections`, it shows some different object string. Any idea how to return the actual value of the temp variable?

```
  def get_person_connections(options = {})
    person_id = options[:id]
    path = "/people/id=" + person_id + ":(num-connections)" 
    query_connections(path, options)
    self
  end
```

and

```
private

def query_connections(path, options={})
  fields = options.delete(:fields) || LinkedIn.default_profile_fields

  if options.delete(:public)
    path +=":public"
  elsif fields
    path +=":(#{fields.map{ |f| f.to_s.gsub("_","-") }.join(',')})"
  end

  headers = options.delete(:headers) || {}

  params = options.map { |k,v| v.is_a?(Array)  ? v.map{|i| "#{k}=#{i}"}.join("&") : "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("&")

  path   += "?#{params}" if not params.empty?

  temp_var = get(path, headers)

  hash = JSON.parse(temp_var)
  conn = hash["numConnections"]
end
```

Comment: Could you show the `get_person_connections` function?

Comment: First, you don't need to use `return`. In Ruby, the last statement will be returned. Also, it'd be helpful to tell what is *some different object string*.

Comment: Just edited the original question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [best practice for return values from ruby methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216510/best-practice-for-return-values-from-ruby-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Samy said in a comment:

> In Ruby, the last statement will be returned.

So if we take a look at `get_person_connections`, we see that the last line is `self`. What it means is that it returns the instance on which the method was called, `@client` in this case.

---

**Additional notes**: the solution would be to remove `self`, although if the method is used elsewhere be careful as returning `self` is often used to allow chaining of methods (though it hardly makes sense to do that on a `get` method).

Comment: so now I do this:         hash = JSON.parse(temp_var)
        conn = hash["numConnections"]
        puts conn.inspect and in displays the number. But on the original function, the value is still the object.  So the number isnt getting assigned.

Comment: If you want `query_connections` to return the number of connections, leave it as it is in your question. If you want `get_person_connections` to also return the number of connections, remove the last `self`. The methods are called like this: `@client. get_person_connections` -> `query_connections` (so the return value of `query_connections` is sent to `get_person_connections`, and the return value of `get_person_connections` is assigned to `person_connections`.